# How to do USB tethering with an Android Froyo and a Mac OS X?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, tethering, macos

With Android Froyo (OS 2.2), how can I do USB tethering with a Mac OS X?

Comment: It is worthwhile noting that HTC phones have their own mechanism for doing USB tethering

Comment: Android 2.1 and HTC Hero here; HTC's tethering didn't work, but PDAnet does work over USB.

Comment: Note that Android 2.3.4 (e.g. on MyTouch 4G slide) has an option to switch between "windows" and "mac osx" when setting up usb tethering, in case you can upgrade the Android OS.

Answer (score 4):

PDAnet: http://www.junefabrics.com/android/mac.php

Comment: I was hoping for using the native Froyo tethering support, but oh well!

Comment: That will depend on whether your carrier supports it and if they do it will cost more for two monyhs of the service than pdanets one time cost.

Comment: assuming carrier's support, do you where I can get the Mac drivers?

Comment: @notnoop:  It depends on your carrier but the ones that support it push it out in the 2.2 OTA update, and if your computer requires extra driver they will be installed from your phone (thats how it happens on Windows, I don't really know about Macs).  If your carrier supports it, you can go into Settings > Wireless & networks and you should see an option for "Tethering & portable hotspot."  If you don't see that I don't think your carrier supports it.  Either way, you can always use PDAnet.

Answer (score 2):

[EasyTether Lite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/easytether-lite/com.mstream.easytether_beta) works for me. I've used it on an XP machine as well as a Mac. I love that it's cross-platform.

> Shares your phone Internet connection
>   with computer/laptop/notebook (Windows
>   7/Vista/XP 64-bit/32-bit, Mac OS X
>   10.4/10.5/10.6, Ubuntu 10.4+). EasyTether works via USB.
>
> Does not need root access.

There's also [EasyTether Full](http://www.appbrain.com/app/easytether/com.mstream.easytether_polyclef).

> Full app allows https - access to
>   secure sites such as facebook, gmail,
>   online banking etc.
>
> Full app allows you to tether ps3,
>   xbox 360, wii via your PC - enable
>   Internet Connection Sharing on your
>   computer for that.