# How do I tether over USB in MacOSX?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, tethering, macos

How do I tether over USB in MacOSX?

I plug the phone in, pick up:

> USB tethering
>
> Share phone's mobile network with PC

which causes the computer to *discover* a new network interface, but it doesn't just work and the configuration looks like this:

[image]

Which telephone number, account name and password is it asking for? I've never got those details from the ISP. I did ask the ISP and the details they gave me made no sense and didn't work.

I'm running the stock Android 2.2 on an HTC Desire, the carrier is Swisscom in Switzerland. I've been told by someone that has the same phone, that plugging it in Windows and doing the same just works without asking for any number or password.

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: [USB Tethering and Mac](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/usb-tethering-and-mac) ...and see if it helps. It's almost a duplicate but I won't close this one because it has a lot more specifics in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://androidforums.com/htc-desire/62464-desire-tethering-mac.html), you need to use software like [PdaNet](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/index.php) to get it to work.

Comment: +1 PdaNet, especially for those who don't want to root

Comment: I'm really surprised it doesn't work out of the box on MacOSX even when it does on Ubuntu... oh well... Something important to add is that at least these days, for mac and android, PdaNet seems to be free.

Comment: The free version only allows you to access sites that you don't have to login to (eg. No Gmail, Facebook...).  If you are going to use it regularly I'd say it's well worth the one time cost of $30.